# I get the error SCRIPT1003: Expected ':' in IE 11; (Java Script Code error)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-11

This particular snippet of JS code does not work on IE 11.  I get the error SCRIPT1003: Expected ':' and it says it is missing on line that it's in bold.

```
var $actions = application.service('$actions', [
function() {
    let _logout = function() {
        $('#logoutForm').submit();
    }
    return {
        **Logout() {**
            _logout();
        },
    };
}]);
```

Any ideas?  Thank you

Comment: `**Logout() {**` whöt is thät and `},` thät?

Comment: ** around text should have BOLD the text, but it did not.

Answer (score 1):

IE11 does not support shorthand method names. See the compatability part of the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer). Use

```
return {
   Logout: function() {
       _logout();
   }
};
```

(or stop supporting internet exploder, if you have the opportunity to - it causes a lot of headache)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.  Your suggestion fixed the problem.  I wish we could tell the customer to discontinue IE but we can't.  I love the "Exploder" name.

Comment: Is there any babel polyfill for ie11?

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa I don't think "polyfill" is the right thing for this, as it is syntax sugar. However, if babel is set to emit ES5 or lower, [it should do the conversion](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=DYUwLgBA9hC8EG8BQEIDMCuA7AFASkQgCdwMisIBmAbggF8k7qg&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.12.12&externalPlugins=) (IE doesn't support ES6 anyways)